# forkJoin on NestJS not working after migration to newer version

Tags: rxjs, nestjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm running nestjs application and have a peace of code that using forkJoin

```
const results: string[] = [];
const args = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4', 'arg5', 'arg6'];

....
switchMap(() => {
   const setToHandle = [];
   args.forEach(arg => setToHandle.push(this.doWorksAndGetResult(arg)));
   return forkJoin(setToHandle);
}),
tap(() => {
   this.logService.debug(...results);
})
```

So this work fine, and I got results printed to log.
But this **forkJoin(setToHandle)** is deprecated now and should use like that
**forkJoin([setToHandle])** according the documentation.
But it isn't work, no results printed in log, no observables called inside doWorksAndGetResult function.
Can some one help me with it?

Comment: @churill the code that I put above is replica of working code.
It's still working, but with warning about deprecation.
The given [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/array-argument) for it, so I do as described there. Even when I subscribing, it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding enough code to get your example to work, I found that strongly typing setToHandle fixed the issue. (At least in my version of your code.)

```
const setToHandle: string[] = [];
```

Otherwise, I think that the language service is getting confused.

UPDATE based on your comments:

This initialization is not valid:

```
const setToHandle: Observable<void> = [];
```

You can't initialize an `Observable<void>` to an empty array []. And you can't then later in your code `push` to an `Observable<void>`

Could you provide enough working code for us to get a better idea of what you are trying to do. See this Stackblitz for a place to start: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yp3ocd

UPDATE 2 based on your later comments:

`forkJoin() takes in an array.`

```
const setToHandle: Observable<boolean>[] = [];
```

`setToHandle` is already defined as an array.

Passing in `[setToHandle]` is putting the array into another array.

If you really need to use the square brackets, then this works:

```
return forkJoin([...setToHandle]);
```

The spread operator (...) expands the array.

Comment: Hello Deborah.
Thank you for your time and effort to help me with this issue, I really appreciate it.
Unfortunately, that didn't help either.
`
const setToHandle: Observable<void> = [];
`
Inside the doWorksAndGetResult function code that reaching to the db 
`
return from(this.typeORM.query('SELECT ....'))
     .pipe(
               switchMap((res) => {
               **console.log("I'm here!!!");**
                   // do something
                   this.results.push(some_variable);
                   return of();
               }));
`

Comment: It is not getting to **console.log("I'm here!!!")**

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: Hi Deborah.
Please take a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nkifwk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I am using the above link and don't see an issue?

Comment: Hi @Deborah.
[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nkifwk?file=src/app/app.component.ts) I'm altered code to show the issue. There is must be output in console (Line 24), but it doesn't. If you will change **return forkJoin([setToHandle]);** to **return forkJoin(setToHandle);** you will see the output (line 21).
But it should work in this well too **return forkJoin([setToHandle]);**

Comment: See Update 2 above.

Comment: Thanks a lot Deborah!!!
It's really works!